# Iterate through JSON object finite number of times in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, while-loop

Trying to develop a web scraper that loops through a JSON object ***responses*** a finite number of times for testing purposes. Program so far:

```
links = []

i = 0
while i < 3:
    for response[i] in responses:
        url = response[i]["PlayerProfile"]
        playername = response[i]["playername"]
        browser = init_browser()
        browser.visit(url)
        html = browser.html
        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        img_url = soup.find("img").text
        links.append({
            "playername": playername,
            "img_url": img_url
        })
i += 1
```

Loop runs for more than 3 iterations; while loop doesn't seem to work. Would like to view output first before setting loop to run 3,000 times. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
for response[i] in responses:
```

This makes `response[i]` the **target** of the `for` loop; each element of `responses` is assigned to `response[i]`. You don't show what `response` *is* in your code; perhaps it's a list with at least 3 elements, or it's a dictionary. Either way, it is being altered.

The syntax is `for target in iterable: body`, where Python will take each element from *`iterable`*, assigns it to *`target`* and execute the body.

So, if `responses` is `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam']`, then the combination of your `while` loop and your `for` loop is this:

1. `while` loop starts with `i = 0`, then the `for` loop runs with `response[0]` as the target, setting:

   - `response[0] = 'foo'`
   - `response[0] = 'bar'`
   - `response[0] = 'baz'`
   - `response[0] = 'spam'`

   and your `for` loop body then uses `response[0]` with each value in turn.
2. `while` continues with `i = 1`, then the `for` loop runs with `response[1]` as the target, setting:

   - `response[1] = 'foo'`
   - `response[1] = 'bar'`
   - `response[1] = 'baz'`
   - `response[1] = 'spam'`

   and your `for` loop body then uses `response[1]` with each value in turn.
3. `while` continues with `i = 2`, then the `for` loop runs with `response[2]` as the target, setting:

   - `response[2] = 'foo'`
   - `response[2] = 'bar'`
   - `response[2] = 'baz'`
   - `response[2] = 'spam'`

   and your `for` loop body then uses `response[2]` with each value in turn.

In the end, you'll have a `response` object with values for `0`, `1` and `2` all set to `'spam'`.

Note that you already *have* a `while` loop, you *don't need a `for` loop as well*. You want to use `response = responses[i]` to do the assignment yourself:

```
while i < 3:
    response = responses[i]

    # ...
    i += 1
```

or you can use a `for` loop over a `range()` object to give you the increasing `i` values:

```
for i in range(3):
    response = responses[i]
```

or you can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to limit the iteration to the first 3 items:

```
from itertools import islice

for response in islice(responses, 3):
    # use response
```

You can also directly slice `responses` if it is a sequence object (a list or tuple):

```
for response in responses[:3]:
    # use response
```

but this requires creating a copy of that part of the `responses` sequence first!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the breakdown my fundamentals are shaky.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to indent `i += 1` another level so it increments for each response. (Also, you don't need the semicolon.) But you don't really need a for loop and while loop to do this, I don't think. How about something like this:

```
for e,i in enumerate(responses):
    if e > 2:
        break
    # edit all variables like this
    url = i["PlayerProfile"]
```